# Unable to web service tester page in net beans 7.1 using glassfish server

Tags: web-services, netbeans-7

Unable to open my web service tester page from net beans, i am getting a error (see the attached image).

But i am able to go to the tester page from the admin console with the same URL.

Is that any problem with creation of WSDL ?[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure what is going on here. I occasionally get this as well. An undeploy followed by a clean and build of the project and a redeploy always tend to solve it for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Your question has been answered at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905880/make-sure-the-service-has-been-deployed-successfully-and-the-server-is-runnig/24906228#24906228) address.**

**Answer :**

```
 <jvm-options>-Duser.language=tr-TR</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Xrs</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
```

Add the above code "glassfish-4.0 \ glassfish \ domains \ domain1 \ config \ domain.xml" directory.

**Ex:**

**1- )**

```
.
.
.
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:NewRatio=2</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Duser.language=tr-TR</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xrs</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
.
.
.
```

**2- )**

```
.
.
.
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Duser.language=tr-TR</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xrs</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

If deploy and un-deploy does not work>>

Go to `tools->options`.

Choose a web browser, no proxy in proxy settings and click test connection.

If the connection is `OK`, deploy the web service and test. The tester page should open now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I fixed it..

- clean and build project
- deploy project
- test web service

After opened Web Service Tester page.