# make sure the service has been deployed successfully, and the server is runnig

Tags: java, web-services, web, glassfish

I creating new java web application, add web service to project. I testing web service  without no edit on project after make clean and built and deploy, and I see this error message "make sure the service has been deployed successfully, and the server is runnig."

why  I may taking error message.

[the image of project directory .](http://seven.gen.tr/images/project_directory.png)

```
package Service;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

/**
 *
 * @author seref
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
public class NewWebService {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

Glassfish Server error message

```
Info:   Invoking wsimport with http://localhost:8080/WebServiceApp/NewWebService?WSDL
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[NewWebService]: Servlet.service() for servlet NewWebService threw exception
java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: bundle://218.0:1/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'bundle' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property. 
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.SchemaCache.newValidator(SchemaCache.java:80)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.apply(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:237)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:541)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2298)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:198)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:141)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:444)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:205)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:183)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.util.WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.wsimport(WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.spi.WSToolsObjectFactory.wsimport(WSToolsObjectFactory.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.wsImport(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:642)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.initializePort(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:528)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doGet(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doGet(JAXWSServlet.java:210)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: bundle://218.0:1/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'bundle' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4162)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaFatalError(XSDHandler.java:4141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2168)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:2078)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1008)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:620)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:616)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:574)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:540)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:638)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:670)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.SchemaCache.newValidator(SchemaCache.java:77)
    ... 47 more

Info:   parsing WSDL...
Info:   [WARNING] schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'NewWebService?xsd=1', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
Info:   line 4 of http://localhost:8080/WebServiceApp/NewWebService?WSDL#types?schema1
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937494/cannot-deploy-webservice-with-netbeans-and-glassfish-server?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <jvm-options>-Duser.language=tr-TR</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Xrs</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
```

Add the above code "glassfish-4.0 \ glassfish \ domains \ domain1 \ config \ domain.xml" directory.

**Ex:**

**1- )**

```
.
.
.
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:NewRatio=2</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Duser.language=tr-TR</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xrs</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
.
.
.
```

**2- )**

```
.
.
.
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Duser.language=tr-TR</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xrs</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
.
.
.
```